# Hide file extension with htaccess 

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, markdown

I'm not the best with mod rewrite so if anybody can help me out here that would be great.

I'm using a markdown processor script and it's using rewrite to grab any files that end with a markdown file type. However, I'd like this script to grab any files within a folder, rather than any files that end with the markdown file type.

Here's the `htaccess`:

```
# display Markdown as HTML by default
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .+\.(markdown|mdown|md|mkd)$ /static/includes/markdown/render.php
RewriteRule .+\.(markdown|mdown|md|mkd)\-text$ /static/includes/markdown/render.php [L]
```

Is there a way to grab all files within a folder called (let's say) "folder" and eliminate the file type on the end?

So maybe have a URL like

```
website.com/home
```

that actually is

```
website.com/home.md
```

and is processed with the markdown script?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The re-write module and it's `.htaccess` files actually work on a per folder basis. Usually one would have a main `.htaccess` file in the web root of a site/server. However you can add numerous `.htaccess` files throughout your site's folder structure giving each individual folder specific rules.

All you would have to do is add another `.htaccess` file to your markdown folder and enable it to parse URL's without file extensions, forwarding it to a script which will be able to detect what original file was requested -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/includes/markdown/render.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Basically what is happening here is that any file requested within this folder will be passed through your `render.php` file.

Now in your `render.php` file, you would have a `$_GET` parameter of `file` containing the original URL. For a url of `http://example.com/markdown/foo`, your `render.php` would have `foo` in the `file` parameter -

```
 /static/includes/markdown/render.php?file=foo
```

If you set the correct headers in `render.php` it will be able to print out any format of file, hiding it's extension in a "fake" URL.

Comment: thanks a lot for this help! This will give me a good starting point!

Comment: You're welcome! The most important thing to take from this is that you can have per folder htaccess files.

Comment: Yeah that's helped a lot. My system is working as expected now! Just need to rewrite the folder now and remove it from url.